# Navigation Bar Acting Strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, uinavigationbar, jsfiddle, visual-web-developer

My nav bar I designed in JsFiddle is acting weird.  sometimes the hamburger menu does not work at all and other times it opens and closes the menu 5+ times.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

It works fine when I get rid of the window width function, but I don't want it to behave the same when it is above 768 pixels since the hamburger menu is no longer needed at large screen sizes.

I believe it has something to do with this:

```
$(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(w <= 768){
        $('.mobile-toggle').click(function(){
        $('nav').slideToggle(500);
        this.classList.toggle('change');
 });

  $('.m-link').click(function(){
      $('.m-link').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('nav').slideToggle(500);
      $('.mobile-toggle').removeClass('change')
  });
 }else{
      $('nav').show();
 }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisFred96/zg4nprfm/56/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it’s to do with the resolution and how it changes. My understanding is that it’s not fixed if you change the resolution.

```css
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 6px);
  background-color: red;
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.5px, -7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.5px, -7px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It is a JS issue.  I fixed it partially, but I am now running into an issue of trying to always make the items appear regardless of the mobile status when screen resize occurs.